# What regular expression to use to get a string that follows a certain word?

Tags: python, regex

Hi I am still a beginner and have been trying to figure out how to use regular expression on this string:

```
Name: Brenden Walski
```

I want to get the value of the name or basically I want to get everything after the "Name: ". I am using python by the way.Please help. Thank You!

Comment: You dont' need a regex for this. You can just split on a colon and the strip the output of that. `string.split(':').strip()`

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression way:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Name: Brenden Walski"
>>> re.findall(r'^Name:(.*?)$', s)[0]
' Brenden Walski'
```

The regular expression is `^Name:(.*?)$`, which means:

- `^` = "start of line"
- `Name:` = the literal string "Name:"
- `(.*?)` = "everything" - the () turns it in a capturing group, which means the match is returned
- `$` = "end of line"

The long way of saying it is *"The start of line, followed by the characters "Name:", then followed by one or more of any printable character, followed by the end of line"*

The "other" way:

```
>>> s.split(':')[1]
' Brenden Walski'
```

The "other" way, when the name might include a `:`:

```
>>> s[s.find(':')+1:]
' Brenden Walker: Jr'
```

Comment: why use a non-greedy match? `(.*?)$` is equivalent to `(.*)` when the `re.DOTALL` flag is not given.

Comment: and `(.*?)` does not mean everything... it only works that way because you have added `$` after it. Otherwise, it would match **nothing** (or the shortest sequence leading up to the following character).

Comment: You can remove the `$` (and of course `?`) and it would still work. However, this answer was not meant to be a crash course in regular expressions - besides, for this specific string I would just use split().

Comment: however, in your answer, you state `(.*?)` matches everything - this is misleading and technically incorrect, since it is the expression `(.*?)$` which matches everything to the end of the line. Since you used a non-greedy operator, the expression following it is important.

Comment: Okay, you can propose an edit to the question with your preferred explanation and I will accept it :)